# Export a simple R dataframe to txt tsv or csv

Tags: r

I am trying to do something apparently obvious, but have no way to solve it. From a dataframe in R downloaded from the web as follows I need to save the data. Here is how I do download it:

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
ts <- get.hist.quote(instrument="DJIA", 
                     start="2008-07-01", end="2017-03-05", 
                     quote="Close", provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01",
                     compression="d", retclass="zoo")
```

Then, returns object "ts"  with a two columns table; the first of dates (with no header as R prefers) and the other with the "Close" value of DJIA

```
            > ts
                  Close
    2008-07-01 11382.26
    2008-07-02 11215.51
    2008-07-03 11288.53
    2008-07-07 11231.96
    .
    .
    .
    2016-03-03 16943.90
    2016-03-04 17006.77
```

I need this data exported in txt or similar format and import the list later; (because I will try to process health information, with no internet access) but when I try to save it; the date column with no header is missing. Additionally a "number of row" column is added. I do appologize if the question is obvious but have no other option to solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write xts/zoo object to csv with index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748721/write-xts-zoo-object-to-csv-with-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date column has no header, because the date is imported as rownames/index. The default of `write.csv` has `row.names = FALSE`. Try:

`write.csv(ts, file = "ts.csv",row.names=TRUE)`

**EDIT**
Strangly, this doesn't work with an object of `class "zoo"`

According tot `? write.table`:

> write.table prints its required argument x (after converting it to a
>   data frame if it is not one nor a matrix) to a file or connection.

Apparently this conversion fails somehow. However, this works:
`write.csv(data.frame(ts), file = "ts.csv",row.names=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes RHA; I've tried this before; but the *.csv file has not the same data as displayed by ts in R and that's my difficulty

Comment: @Mario then please show in your question what goes wrong. Or try converting the rownames to a column. See edited answer above!

Comment: ts.csv displays the following
; ,"Close"
1,11382.259766
2,11215.509766
3,11288.530273
4,11231.959961

But it not displays the dates in standard characters
2008-07-01 11382.26

Comment: @Mario You are right, this doesn't work for zoo objects. Posted a solution above, hope it works for you too!

Comment: YESSSSS My dear @RHA it worked fine! But it took me a lot to go nowhere; because in addition to the difficulty i am learning R Oh ; Thanks Thanks & thanks again my friend!

Comment: @Mario You're welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, then please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the accept mark left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ts` object is a zoo object (not a two column table).  In this case the zoo object is internally represented by a one column matrix of data and an `"index"` attribute holding the dates.

**1) save/load** If the only thing you want to do with the output file is to read it back into R later then there is no reason to require text and any format will do.  In particular you could do this:

```
save(ts, file = "ts.Rda")
```

Now in a later session:

```
library(zoo)
load("ts.Rda")
```

**1a)** This would also work and produces an R source file that when sourced reconstructs the zoo object:

```
dump("ts", "ts.R")
```

and in a later session:

```
library(zoo)
source("ts.R")
```

**2) write.zoo/read.zoo**  This will give a text file:

```
write.zoo(ts, "ts.dat")
```

and it can be written back in another session using:

```
library(zoo)
ts <- cbind( read.zoo("ts.dat", header = TRUE) )
```

Comment: Added second approach.